# Rate of depletion: Population change - Differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization

Given some stock
$A$ that decreased over a period according to
$A = −12.5t + 175$,

where $0\leq t\leq5 $
and $t=0$ represents year 2015.

If the stock continues to decrease at the same *rate*, when will it be depleted?
I don’t think it can be as simple as saying
saying:
$$A= −12.5t + 175 = 0, \Rightarrow t =175/12.5 \Rightarrow t = 14  $$
I feel this misses something important about the rate remaining constant?

Comment: I should add that I’m guessing this might involve an ordinary differential equation but it’s been a while since I was in school and looked at ODEs & PDEs

Comment: That equation must be the rate of change of A not the value of A itself.

Comment: $A \rightarrow \frac{\text{d}(A)}{\text{dt}}$

Comment: It is the equation for a stock A over a period of t=5 years.

Comment: Though it doesn't seem to give the right answer

Comment: Then I guess, question is that simple.. though the interval on t is bugging me

Comment: The rate of change is $\frac{dA}{dt}=-12.5$, and this stays constant in time. Unfortunately, it's not obvious what to do when $t>5$.